# swift send struct data from class to instance

Tags: swift, static

I made a static library in C language.
The functions of this library are as follows.

1. Save the callback function point in a global variable
2. The callback function has a parameter of the struct structure.
3. The library transmits struct data by calling the callback function to the library user at a specific moment.

The source for this is:

1. static library source

```
// ---------------------------------------------
// Static Library
// ---------------------------------------------
typedef struct
{
  unsigned long m_Data1;
  unsigned long m_Data2;
  unsigned long m_Data3;
} SEND_DATA;

//
typedef int (*ReportCallbackProc)(SEND_DATA *pSendData);

//
static ReportCallbackProc gReportFunc = NULL;
static Period = 0;

// Set callback function pointer to gloval variable
int SetReport(ReportCallbackProc func, int period)
{
  gReportFunc = func;
  Period = period;

  return(1);
}

// Send data to Application of library
void Report()
{
   .............
   SEND_DATA sendData;
   sendData.m_Data1 = 1;
   sendData.m_Data2 = 2;
   sendData.m_Data3 = 3;

   int rc = gReportFunc(&sendData);
   if (rc != 1)
   {
      printf("gRealtimeReportFunc failed: status=[%d]\n", rc);
   }

    .....
}
```

2. application of this library

```
// ---------------------------------------------
// Application of Static Library
// ---------------------------------------------
void handle_report (SEND_DATA *pSendData)
{
   printf("Report called");
   printf("m_Data1 = %ld ", pSendData->m_Data1);
   printf("m_Data2 = %ld ", pSendData->m_Data2);
   printf("m_Data3 = %ld ", pSendData->m_Data3);
}

void main()
{
    SetReport (&handle_report, period);
}
```

---

I want to make the above source in swift. Currently, I am trying to implement while studying swift.
However, it is not an easy problem and asks for help.
I tried creating and implementing closure usage and classes, but it was never easy.

Can you provide similar swift code?
Can you tell me how to implement it?

Comment: What does "similar swift code" mean? What are you asking us to do? No one is going to write your code for you. You need to _show_ us your Swift code and explain what the difficulty is. Functions are first-class citizens in Swift, so it's hard to imagine what the difficulty could be. Please explain. Thanks.

Comment: This is very confusing. First, what does `period` serve for? Second, you call `SetReport` and hand in `&handle_report`, which is a _void_ function – but the `Report` function calls that callback (`handle_report`) and expects an _int_ return value. This will only work in C and will result in undefined behaviour. Third, please please please adapt to the naming convetions of any C style language not written by Microsoft: Types begin with a upper case letter, variables and functions with a lower case letter.